# energy unit conversions

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hvac

This is an HVAC mechanical engineering question on a document from a manufacture where they convert units of electrical energy to therms of natural gas.

Carrier has writeups for building energy simulation modeling, and [this link](https://www.shareddocs.com/hvac/docs/1004/public/0a/hap_ehelp_031.pdf) is a PDF for a writeup using the HAP software.

Question:
The example on page 2 as a high level feasibility they convert units of NG to kWh:

> In a certain locale the price for electricity is 0.0960 dollar per
>   killowatt hour and the cost of natural gas is 0.937 dollar per therm.
>   If we convert the gas price to use units of kWh, we get a gas price of
>   0.0320 $/kWh. Therefore a kWh of electricity is three  times as expensive as a kWh of natural gas. If the average annual COP of the
>   DHRC is more than three times that of the gas boiler, then heating
>   cost will be reduced by using the DHRC. If the COP of the DHRC is less
>   than three times that of the boiler, heating cost will increase. Note:
>   This is a single example for illustration. Energy prices vary widely
>   by location and over time. You should use your own local utility
>   prices to assess heat recovery viability for your projects.

I know 1 therm = 29.3001 kWh or 1 kWh = 0.03413 therm.

But what’s the math behind coming up with “convert the gas price to use units of kWh, we get a gas price of 0.0320 $/kWh”?

Comment: 0.03414*0.937=~0.032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is just that you're expecting the solution to be more elegant; it looks like you already have it pretty much figured out.

[image: equation with terms dropped out]